# Updating image to database php

Tags: php, sql

So my image isn't updating to the databse and i'm getting this error:

```
Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: No error in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpfinal\pic_upload.php on line 36 error
```

I googled this and came up with nothing. Please help
I've commented out where line 37 is

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    $username = $_SESSION['sUserName']; 
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "writes", "digger")or die("cannot connect"); 
    mysqli_select_db($conn,phpfinal)or die("cannot select DB");
    ?>

    </head>
    <body>
    <span style="color:#FF0000"><?php echo $msg; ?></span><br />
    <h2>Select File to upload</h2>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
    <input name="userfile" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"  name="Submit"/>
    </form>
    <?php
    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"]=='image/gif') || ($_FILES["file"]["type"]=='image/jpeg'))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"]<10000000))
    {
    if($_FILES["file"]["error"]>0)
    {
    } else {
    $structure = 'uploaded_files/' .$username ."/";
    }
    }
    if (file_exists ($structure))
    { 
    move_uploaded_file ($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $structure .$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $img = $structure .$_FILES["file"]["name"];

} else {
    mkdir($structure);
//line 37
    move_uploaded_file ($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $structure .$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $img = $structure .$_FILES["file"]["name"];
}
$sql = "UPDATE users SET structure='image' WHERE username = '$username'";
//I'm not sure if the above line is right or wrong 

$result = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql) or die(error);
print_r($result);
if($result){
echo "Update successful";
}
?>
```

Comment: btw i'm a complete noob at this so please explain it to me like i'm an infant lol

Comment: Well, if the warning says there is no error on line 36 then it must be true...or not.

Comment: I wonder what `mkdir()` has to do with databases...

Answer (score 0):

It is because you send an empty string to mkdir (worst error message of the world I guess ;)

Check your code :

```
if($_FILES["file"]["error"]>0)
{
} else {
  $structure = 'uploaded_files/' .$username ."/";
}
```

If you have an error in your upload, *$structure* is not set. I recommand you to use error_reporting(E_ALL) to avoid being stuck with such of errors.

Comment: Problem solved. I feel like an idiot. I changed SET structure='image' to SET image='$structure'